# Can't resolve validationmessages.properties

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

When I run my project, localized validation messages located in **src/main/resources** (when the project is not packaged and run with an IDE-embedded runner) or **WEB-INF/classes** (when the project is packaged and deployed) are not resolved. I always get the default messages.

Yet, when I am running tests, the messages are resolved properly...

I use vanilla validation (Spring does not interfere).

```
validator = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().messageInterpolator(new LocaleAwareMessageInterpolator(locale)).buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```

LocaleAwareMessageInterpolator extends the standard ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.

```
public class LocaleAwareMessageInterpolator extends ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator {
  private Locale defaultLocale = Locale.FRENCH;

  public LocaleAwareMessageInterpolator(Locale defaultLocale) {
    this.defaultLocale = defaultLocale;
  }

  @Override
  public String interpolate(final String messageTemplate, final Context context) {
    return interpolate(messageTemplate, context, defaultLocale);
  }

  @Override
  public String interpolate(final String messageTemplate, final Context context, final Locale locale) {
    try {
      return super.interpolate(messageTemplate, context, locale);
    } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError e) {...}
  }
}
```

Should I move them to another location ? 
Should I set some parameters somewhere to give out the location of the .properties ?

Comment: What is the exact name and location of the properties file? It should be ValidationMessages.properties in the root of the classpath. src/main/resources is not a place it gets picked up from though. This is a source location, the build (whatever tool or IDE you are using) copies the file to another location. It might also help to see your code for LocaleAwareMessageInterpolator.

Comment: Thanks. The name is ValidationMessages.properties. The deployment path is WEB-INF/classes. I'll post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem byt passing a PlatformResourceBundleLocator in the ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator constructor. I don't know why the system couln't get the ValidationMessages from WEB-INF/classes (I thought it was automatic), but this works.

```
public LocaleAwareMessageInterpolator(Locale defaultLocale) {
   super(new PlatformResourceBundleLocator("ValidationMessages"));
   this.defaultLocale = defaultLocale;
}
```

[Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-using-specific-resource-bundle-locator) is pretty clear about it. I missed that.